# neo4jphp: Is it possible to retrieve a node by a property?

Tags: php, neo4j

I'm using **neo4jphp** to work with a neo4j database using PHP. It has this method for selecting a node from the database:

`$select = $neo->getNode(4); // 4 is the node's id`

However, I will not always know the *id* for the node I want. So is it possible to select a node by its property instead?

For example:

`$select = $neo->getNode('name', 'Greg');`

---

https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Nodes-and-Relationships

Comment: I don't know the syntax for doing this with php, but matching to a node (or nodes) based on properties is the most common approach with neo4j. In fact users should avoid saving the internal ids of nodes and using them for later lookup, as the internal node ID may change, and as node IDs can be reused after nodes are deleted, which could result in buggy queries.

Comment: @InverseFalcon: Thanks for mentioning. I'm new to neo4j and assumed matching nodes based on properties would be the best way to go. Thought it was awkward to only be able to match nodes based on id using neo4jphp, if this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using indexes, labels, or using Cypher queries. There is no built-in way in neo4jphp to query for nodes by property.

Also, neo4jphp is built for an earlier version of Neo4j. If you are using a more recent version of Neo4j, I would recommend using a more up-to-date library for connecting Neo4j to a PHP application: https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation (and also for neo4jphp), Josh.